# Image Uploading with FormData multiple inputs

Tags: php, ajax, upload, form-data

How I can use FormData with multiple file inputs?

```
<input type="file" id="file1">

<input type="file" id="file2">

<input type="file" id="file3">
```

Comment: There is a jQuery package for uploads that allows multiple files. https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @liquidacid how to make it start upload automatically without click start upload

Answer (score 1):

Now `html5` support multiple file upload in one input filed ! If you want to start upload auto without click , you should do by `onchange` method . From ajax , you must use `new FormData()` .

upload.php

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="filefield" multiple="multiple">
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#files").on("change",function(){
    var ajaxData = new FormData();
    var obj = $(this)[0];
    $.each(obj.files,function(i,file){
        ajaxData.append("file['"+i+"']",file);
    });
    $.ajax({
        url :'index.php',
        data: ajaxData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        type:"POST",
        success : function() {

        }
    });
})
```

index.php

```
<?php
  var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```